# node-mssql - User authentication fails when specifying database

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to SQL server using the node-mssql package.

I can successfully connect to the default database with the following configuration:

```
{
   "user": "service_user",
   "password": "myPass",
   "server": "10.2.xxx.xxx",
}
```

However, there are multiple databases I would like to connect to. When I try configuring my connection to target a specific database, like so, it fails:

```
{
   "user": "service_user",
   "password": "myPass",
   "server": "10.2.xxx.xxx",
   "database": "Q-xxx-SQL-xxx\\DB2"
}
```

I have also tried to this configuration that also fails:

```
{
   "user": "service_user",
   "password": "myPass",
   "server": "10.2.xxx.xxx\\Q-xxx-SQL-xxx",
   "database": "DB2"
}
```

When I try to connect to a specific DB, I get the following error:

```
{ ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'service_user'.
       at ConnectionError (/Users/name/Desktop/SCIM API-MSSQL/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:13:12)
       at Parser.tokenStreamParser.on.token (/Users/name/Desktop/SCIM API-MSSQL/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:735:29)
       at Parser.emit (events.js:189:13)
       at Parser.parser.on.token (/Users/name/Desktop/SCIM API-MSSQL/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/token-stream-parser.js:27:14)
       at Parser.emit (events.js:189:13)
       at addChunk (/Users/name/Desktop/SCIM API-MSSQL/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:297:12)
       at readableAddChunk (/Users/name/Desktop/SCIM API-MSSQL/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:279:11)
       at Parser.Readable.push (/Users/name/Desktop/SCIM API-MSSQL/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:240:10)
       at Parser.Transform.push (/Users/name/Desktop/SCIM API-MSSQL/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:139:32)
       at doneParsing (/Users/name/Desktop/SCIM API-MSSQL/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/stream-parser.js:80:14)
     message: 'Login failed for user \'service_user\'.',
     code: 'ELOGIN' },
  name: 'ConnectionError' }
```

When I log in to the server that is running the DBs, I can successfully read and write into the target DB in SSMS.

Comment: Have you tried: `{
   "user": "service_user",
   "password": "myPass",
   "server": "10.2.xxx.xxx", "database": "DB2"
}`

Comment: I tried that and it is working for the default database, call it DB1. but when I swap in DB2 it throws the same error. Would it have to be a security issue on the DB side? Do not know much about MSSQL honestly.

Comment: The SQL Server error log should have additional information about the cause of the failed login. The likely cause is the user does not have connect permissions to the DB2 database. The solution may be adding the user to he DB2 database (`USE DB2;CREATE USER service_user;`) and granting any needed permissions.